# How to package Python GUI application into Debian package to run on debian based operating system or any other linux systems?

Tags: python, linux, debian, python-packaging, deb

I have an python GUI application that communicates with a web application, the website generates a link to open the desktop application (python app), so i have bash scripts that modify the system variables to make it ready for the system to recognize the link and open the app,

My question is that i want to make a debian package for that app with the files and bash scripts, how to do it??

I tried to convert the python application into one-file using pyinstaller and put bash scripts in same installer folder then run them using another python application that i compiled also with pyinstaller but the error happened telling that pythonlib3.8 not found on the system (Ubuntu 18) and my app developed on Ubuntu 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm). This is a tool specifically for creating packages for different Linux distributions such as Debian or RHEL.

Here is the [documentation](https://fpm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and even specific [example](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm/blob/main/examples/python/twisted/Makefile) for python.